# Format string in JSON format in textarea?

Tags: angular

I have this string:

```
"{filter: [{\"attribute\":\"quoteitemnum\",\"filterOperation\":\"EQUALS\",\"expressionValue\":\"581-2019-2\"}]}"
```

im trying to have nice format json in textarea:

```
 <textarea [ngModel]="request | json" disabled></textarea>
```

But this is not working.

I tried this also:

```
const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(this.request);
this.obj.request = JSON.parse(myObjStr);



  <textarea [ngModel]="obj.request" disabled></textarea>
```

and

```
<textarea [ngModel]="obj.request | json" disabled></textarea>
```

But its not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your string has some backslashes. Have you tried removing them?

Comment: Your string it is little bit complex, as @Lok said did you try to remove them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the string is an invalid JSON string.  When I used the string below it works fine with the `json` pipe.  The filters key is not escaped (`\"filter\"`)

```
"{ \"filter\":[{ \"attribute\":\"quoteitemnum\",\"filterOperation\":\"EQUALS\",\"expressionValue\":\"581-2019-2\"}]}"
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czcsuj

Comment: how can i make it valid because im getting it from backend like that i cannot change it on backend

Comment: You could do a string replace `string.replace('filter', '\"filter\"')`.

Comment: My suggestion is to fix the issue on the backend.  If you absolutely can't,  you can follow @Sam 's suggestions or you could parse out the array value that is being assigned to filter and then rebuild the object.  Something like this.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjzteb

Answer (score 0):

I think the given string should be something like below,

```
"{ \"filter\":[{ \"attribute\":\"quoteitemnum\",\"filterOperation\":\"EQUALS\",\"expressionValue\":\"581-2019-2\"}]}"
```

You didn't escape the filter. And if the `json` string is correct, the `json pipe` should work fine.

```
<textarea style="background-color:black;color:white;"rows="30" cols="50">  
  {{rapidPageValue | json}}                           
</textarea>
```

Instead of textarea you can also make use of `pre` tag

```
  `<pre>{{rapidPageValue | json}}</pre>`
```

Comment: im getting string like that from backend and i cannot modify it to get "valid" json

Answer (score 0):

you can parse json string and use  tag and json pipe

hope this helps...

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rafyyw?file=src/app/app.component.ts**

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.request =
  "{ \"filter\":[{ \"attribute\":\"quoteitemnum\",\"filterOperation\":\"EQUALS\",\"expressionValue\":\"581-2019-2\"}]}";

const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.request));
this.request = JSON.parse(myObjStr);
```

}

Like @Jason White said, wrap the string with **JSON.parse** before doing JSON.stringify

I hope it helps.